# Vagrant: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 lts, and after installing vagrant and some tricks I've runned:

> vagrant up

And I've got an error:

```
    The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
/sbin/ifdown 'eth1' || true
/sbin/ip addr flush dev 'eth1'
# Remove any previous network modifications from the interfaces file
sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-BEGIN/,$ d' /etc/network/interfaces > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
sed -ne '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ p' /etc/network/interfaces | tac | sed -e '/^#VAGRANT-END/,$ d' | tac > /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

cat \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-entry \
  /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post \
  > /etc/network/interfaces

rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.pre
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-entry
rm -f /tmp/vagrant-network-interfaces.post

/sbin/ifup 'eth1'

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

bash: line 5: /sbin/ifdown: No such file or directory
bash: line 21: /sbin/ifup: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I've just had a similar issue. From another stackoverflow answer I type `vagrant up --debug` and then I had to stop the vagrant box with `vagrant halt`, and then again `vagrant up` and it ran normally!